# Tall male in a giant spaceship which in the past was used for biological warfare

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is a collection of stories of the protagonist travelling on his scavenged ship between planets and offering bioengineering services.

Remember one story with an overpopulated planet he was hired to bioengineer food nutritious enough to solve the food shortage problem.

The protagonist is tall (above 7'), bald, aphephobic, misanthropic and has a clowder of cats.

Comment: A prequel to "Alien"?

Comment: This is "Tuf Voyaging" by George RR Martin which has been asked about several times already on the site.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That was my immediate impression from the title alone; the rest of the question just confirms it.

Comment: yes. Tuf Voyaging fits.

Comment: Dupe-hammered since OP confirmed it.

Comment: Remember reading this in Analog ages ago, the Plague Star.  Decades later realized it was the same author of Game of Thrones. And had been holding out that the dragons, white walkers, etc were actually creations from the bio engineering ship and end series would end in space.